# SharePoint job queued, but never starts

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

I'm attempting to retract a solution from SharePoint. I've started the job via Central Admin site as well as from stsadm. The job is queued, however, it will stay in a state of pending for days. The SharePoint services - Admin and Timer service - are started.

Any suggestoins of why the retraction jobs are queued, but never started? I'm really at a loss of what to try next, so anything will be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you run "STSADM -o execadmsvcjobs" from one of the servers on the farm? this should flush the job queue, displaying any errors occurred along the way.

Comment: @x0n: Thank you. That command started the queued job. Do you know why the job wouldn't start without running this command?

Comment: I don't know - the job _should_ start by itself; maybe there is some other setting that is preventing this. Unfortunately I've never had this happen, so don't have any pointers...

Comment: Ran into a similar problem last week. The issue turned out to be at least partly related to permissions on the timer service account - it is possible for the timer service to run without having access to do anything to SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the SharePoint 2010 Timer service is running.